# Convergence of basis expansion with indicator functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be partitioned into disjoint $\Omega_n$ and let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Suppose I now approximate $f$ as
$$f^{(N)} = \sum_{k=1}^N c_k \chi_{\Omega_k}$$
where $\chi$ is the indicator function. If I now let $N\to\infty$ does $f^N$ converge to $f$ in some sense?

Since I only have countably infinite sections $\Omega_k$ but uncountable infinite function values I would not think so, but is there some extended notion of convergence, under which $f^{(N)} \to f$?

Comment: How is $c_k$ determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $c_k$ are independent of $N$, then $f^{(N)}$ will converge pointwise to $f:=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}c_k\chi_{\Omega_k}$ (which is well defined, since for a fixed $x$, at most one term in the sum is not $0$). Moreover, if
$\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\lvert c_k\rvert^p\lambda_n(\Omega_k)$ is finite (where $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^n$), then the convergence takes place in $\mathbb L^p$.